# How to get single value from Crawler filter()?

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler

Using: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte. 
I want to parse single value from a website using following code:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://mig.kz');

$crawler->filter('.buy')->eq(0)->each(function ($node) {                                                                                                                                                
   echo $node->text();                                                                                                                                                                                       
});
```

I can get a single value using `each()`, but is this possible without each? How can i store the first matching value in a variable, then reuse it later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this should do:

```
$crawler->filter('.buy')->first();
```

Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-traversing

From: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte#more-information

[image]

Source: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte#technical-information

Comment: `>>> echo $crawler->filter('.buy')->eq(0)->first();
PHP error:  Object of class Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler could not be converted to string on line 1`

Comment: Although I can't confidently say I used this tool before but based on the example in you question, you may add `->text(); ` to that to convert to string _maybe_ since `echo` itself expects this to be string. Or you can simply `print_r()` this instead

Comment: You can have `$first = $crawler->filter('.buy')->eq(0)->first()->text();` then `echo $first` Okay I found this: accessing the text content of the node: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values

Comment: `>>> echo $crawler->filter('.buy')->eq(0)->first()->text();
310.7⏎
=> null` is that ok? I can save that value to a database?

Comment: I would say you should check the content of `$crawler->filter('.buy')` then `$crawler->filter('.buy')->eq(0)` so you can be sure that even there was nothing wrong with the filter when taking the node with class `.buy` in the first place. And I will advice you test other nodes with this to be sure this result is correct

Comment: The reason I suspect that something might be wrong is because why should it return `null`? Nevertheless, if this is what you think is correct then...I don't have anything to say... my advice is to read the documentation properly: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Comment: damn, it returns `null`? not the value 310.7?

Comment: Didnt you already get the first node with this `$crawler->filter('.buy')->eq(0)` why not try to get the text() property of this? `$crawler->filter('.buy')->eq(0)->text()`